# How to load an .rtfd.zip file into an iPad UIWebView

Tags: ipad, uiwebview

I have an iPad UIWebView which has to display some rtfd.zip files. I try to do it like this:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[self loadFile:string];
}
- (void)loadFile:(NSString*)file
{
NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString* sourceFilePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:sourceFilePath isDirectory:NO];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webview loadRequest:request];
[resourcePath release];
}
```

But I only get a blank page. The outlets are definitely connected properly - the UIWebView can load google main page.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this, I got output by using this,

```
    - (void)loadFile:(NSString*)file    {

        UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc] init];

        NSString *FullstrURL=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:file 
                                                             ofType:@"html" ];
        NSLog(@"HTML String = %@",FullstrURL);
       [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:FullstrURL]]];

 }
```